# Entity manager error in spring-boot application with multiple schemas/databases

Tags: java, spring, entity-framework, hibernate, maven

Attempting to get the following app below to run but have been facing errors which seems to be telling me there is a problem with my entity manager. Thanks for any help in advance.

Config:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.ds_buyer")
    public DataSource buyerDataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.ds_toner")
    public DataSource tonerDataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.ds_manager")
    public DataSource managerDataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

Entity 1:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "toner_buyer")
public class Buyer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "BUYER_ID")
    private int buyerId;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "BUYER_ADDRESS")
    private String buyerAddress;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "MANG_ID")
    private Manager manager;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Toner.class, mappedBy = "buyer",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Toner> toners;

    public Buyer(){}

    public Buyer(String firstName, String lastName, String buyerAddress, Set<Toner> buyerToner) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.buyerAddress = buyerAddress;
        this.toners = buyerToner;
    }

    public int getBuyerId() {
        return buyerId;
    }

    public void setBuyerId(int buyerId) {
        this.buyerId = buyerId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getBuyerAddress() {
        return buyerAddress;
    }

    public void setBuyerAddress(String buyerAddress) {
        this.buyerAddress = buyerAddress;
    }

    public Set<Toner> getBuyerToner() {
        return toners;
    }

    public void setBuyerToner(Set<Toner> buyerToner) {
        this.toners = buyerToner;
    }
}
```

Entity 2:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "toner_manager")
public class Manager {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "MANG_ID")
    private int mid;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private System lastName;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Buyer.class, mappedBy = "manager", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Buyer> buyers;
}
```

Entity 3:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "toner_stock")
public class Toner {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "TONER_ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "TONER_NAME")
    private String tonerName;

    @Column(name = "TONER_PRICE")
    private int tonerPrice;

    @Column(name = "TONER_QUANTITY")
    private int tonerQuantity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "BUYER_ID")
    private Buyer buyer;

    public Toner(){}

    public Toner(int tonerId){
        this.id = tonerId;
    }

    public Toner(String tonerName, int tonerPrice, int tonerQuantity) {
        this.tonerName = tonerName;
        this.tonerPrice = tonerPrice;
        this.tonerQuantity = tonerQuantity;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Toner{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", tonerName='" + tonerName + '\'' +
                ", tonerPrice=" + tonerPrice +
                ", tonerQuantity=" + tonerQuantity +
                '}';
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTonerName() {
        return tonerName;
    }

    public void setTonerName(String tonerName) {
        this.tonerName = tonerName;
    }

    public int getTonerPrice() {
        return tonerPrice;
    }

    public void setTonerPrice(int tonerPrice) {
        this.tonerPrice = tonerPrice;
    }

    public int getTonerQuantity() {
        return tonerQuantity;
    }

    public void setTonerQuantity(int tonerQuantity) {
        this.tonerQuantity = tonerQuantity;
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.ds_toner.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/toner_stock?useSSL=false
spring.ds_toner.username=toner
spring.ds_toner.password=toner
spring.ds_toner.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.ds_manager.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/toner_manager?useSSL=false
spring.ds_manager.username=toner
spring.ds_manager.password=toner
spring.ds_manager.driver-class-name= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.ds_buyer.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/toner_buyer?useSSL=false
spring.ds_buyer.username=toner
spring.ds_buyer.password=toner
spring.ds_buyer.driver-class-name= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
```

Pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ronone</groupId>
    <artifactId>TonerStock</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.39</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>



</project>
```

Print trace:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.2.RELEASE)

2017-05-13 08:00:06.542  INFO 657 --- [           main] com.ronone.Application                   : Starting Application on Ronalds-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 657 (/Users/ronaldpitt/Desktop/TonerStock/target/classes started by ronaldpitt in /Users/ronaldpitt/Desktop/TonerStock)
2017-05-13 08:00:06.546  INFO 657 --- [           main] com.ronone.Application                   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-05-13 08:00:06.823  INFO 657 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@77be656f: startup date [Sat May 13 08:00:06 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-13 08:00:08.549  INFO 657 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fd5e7927] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-05-13 08:00:09.005  INFO 657 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-05-13 08:00:09.031  INFO 657 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-05-13 08:00:09.032  INFO 657 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
2017-05-13 08:00:09.204  INFO 657 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-05-13 08:00:09.206  INFO 657 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2386 ms
2017-05-13 08:00:09.432  INFO 657 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-05-13 08:00:09.438  INFO 657 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-13 08:00:09.439  INFO 657 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-13 08:00:09.439  INFO 657 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-13 08:00:09.439  INFO 657 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-13 08:00:10.420  INFO 657 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-05-13 08:00:10.453  INFO 657 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-05-13 08:00:10.598  INFO 657 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.9.Final}
2017-05-13 08:00:10.600  INFO 657 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-05-13 08:00:10.822  INFO 657 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-05-13 08:00:11.014  INFO 657 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2017-05-13 08:00:11.320  WARN 657 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2017-05-13 08:00:11.327  INFO 657 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2017-05-13 08:00:11.346  INFO 657 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-05-13 08:00:11.355 ERROR 657 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at com.ronone.Application.main(Application.java:9) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:967) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.lang.System, at table: manager, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(last_name)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:455) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:422) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:597) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:889) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    ... 22 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible type at:

```
public class Manager {
    private System lastName;
}
```

You probably meant 'private **String** lastName'